# Why does GaussianFilter not have a periodic option?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

Let us say I have a table:

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {128, 128}];
```

I can filter it using `GaussianFilter` as follows

```
GaussianFilter[tab, 12] // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

But imagine I want the resulting image/cube to be periodic.

**Question**:

> How come `GaussianFilter` not have a Periodic option?

I would ideally want to have

```
 GaussianFilter[tab, 8,Periodic->True] // Image // ImageAdjust
```

to produce something like this?

[image]

This should be easily done using Fourier Transform?

In principle it could work for tensors of any rank, like so?

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {32, 32, 32}]
 GaussianFilter[tab, 8,Periodic->True] // Image3D // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know the `GaussianFilter[]` option `Padding->"Periodic"`  ?
I think that's the option you're looking for!

Your first example

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {256}];
{tab, GaussianFilter[tab, 5,Padding->"Periodic"]} // ListLinePlot
```

evaluates a  periodic result too.

[image]

This option evaluates the 2D-example too

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {128, 128}]; 
GaussianFilter[tab, 12, Padding -> "Periodic"] // Image //ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Comment: Arg! you are right... Oh well so much for spending a few hours coding this :-)

Comment: @Chris Sorry ;-)

Comment: Its on me for not remembering this. I had used it in the past. Mathematica has so many options and ways of implementing them it is a maze.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I cheated a bit: I knew the answer :-)
But I believe it should become a built in option to GaussianFilter!

This function will do the trick for even tensors:

```
fftIndgen[size_] := 
  2. Pi/ size ArrayPad[
    Range[0, Quotient[size, 2]], {0, Quotient[size, 2] - 1}, 
    "ReflectedNegation"];
FourierGaussianFilter::usage = 
  "FourierGaussianFilter[tab,size] does Gaussian periodic filtering";
FourierGaussianFilter::odd = "tensor size should be even";
FourierGaussianFilter[data_, R_] := 
 Module[{d = data // TensorRank, l = data // Length},
  If[OddQ[l] == True, Message[FourierGaussianFilter::odd]; 
   Abort[]];
  InverseFourier[
     Fourier[data]*
      Exp[-0.5 R^2 Map[# . # &, 
         Outer[List, Sequence @@ Table[fftIndgen[l], d]
          ], {d}]
       ]] // Re // Chop]
```

Should work for tensors on any rank. E.g.

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {256}];
{tab, FourierGaussianFilter[tab, 5]} // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

It also works for, say, rank 4 tensors:

```
tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2{8, 8, 8, 8}];
Map[ImageAdjust[Image3D[#]] &, FourierGaussianFilter[tab, 5]]
```

[image]

> It could be improved to work with irregular/odd (hyper)cubes?

Comment: Compare the timing if you have a few moments to spare.

Comment: @syed yes it is not very favourable which is hardly surprising!